# Split a single delimited string into a table for a given number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string that looks like this:

`DECLARE @myString varchar(max) = '1,2,3,4,5,6'`

I want to call a function (or in SOME way convert to a table) that takes as arguments the string, delimiter and an integer, and returns a table that splits the string into columns:

For instance,

`SELECT * FROM somefunction(@mystring,',',2)` should give me a table two columns:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

AND

`SELECT * FROM somefunction(@mystring,',',3)` should give me three columns like so:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Comment: Simple answer; you can't. A `FUNCTION` must returned a defined dataset.

Comment: You *could* do this in a Stored Procedure, however, using dynamic SQL, but this really smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me.

Comment: Well the base problem is trying to parse out the string into a table that gives me more than one column. Either using a proc, or function, doesn't really matter. I don't know how to generalize it any further.

Comment: Why do you need more than 1 column, and why do you need a dynamic number of columns?

Comment: Can you not push the problem back in the other direction - why is something passing a delimited string to SQL, when SQL Server has types *designed* to contain multiple pieces of data?

Comment: I have a list which users can add any number of items to. In the next step this list must be pivoted such that the items become columns. The code behind passes this list in a single string as described above. Technically it doesn't have to be dynamic, my list has three columns, being able to parse the string into triplets would be enough.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's how the table data is represented in the multirow controller in the front-end when its passed around as a passing field to other menu items. I have absolutely no control over being to change this behavior unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to reiterate firstly that this has a strong smell of a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and that very likely this isn't something you should be doing in the RDBMS. That isn't to say it *can't* be, but certainly SQL Server isn't the best place.

Secondly, as mentioned, this is impossible in a `FUNCTION`. A `FUNCTION` must be well defined, meaning the data in and the data out must be defined at the time the function is created. An object that needs to return a variable amount of columns isn't well defined, as you can't define the result until the object is called.

Also the only way to achieve what you are after is by using Dynamic SQL, which you *cannot* use inside a `FUNCTION`; as it requires using `EXEC` (which can only be used against a very few system objects and `sp_executesql` is not one of them).

This means we would need to use a Stored Procedure to achieve this, however, you won't be able to use syntax like `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyProcedure(@mystring,',',2);` You'll need to execute it (`EXEC dbo.MyProcedure(@mystring,',',2);`).

Before we get onto the end dynamic solution, we need to work out how we would do with a static value. That isn't too bad, you need to simply use a a string splitter that is ordinal position aware (`STRING_SPLIT` is **not**), so I am using [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2). Then you can use a bit of integer maths to assign the rows both a column and row group. Finally we can use those value to pivot the data, using a "Cross Tab".

For a non-dynamic approach, this gets us a result like this:

```sql
DECLARE @String varchar(8000),
        @Columns tinyint;

SET @String = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
SET @Columns = 3;

WITH Groupings AS(
    SELECT *,
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) -1) / @Columns AS RowNo,
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) -1) % @Columns +1 AS ColumnNo
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@String,',') DS)
SELECT MAX(CASE G.ColumnNo WHEN 1 THEN G.Item END) AS Col1,
       MAX(CASE G.ColumnNo WHEN 2 THEN G.Item END) AS Col2,
       MAX(CASE G.ColumnNo WHEN 3 THEN G.Item END) AS Col3
FROM Groupings G
GROUP BY G.RowNo;
```

Of course, if you change the value of `@Columns` the number of columns does not change, it's hard coded.

It's also **important** to note I have used a `varchar(8000)` **not** a `varchar(MAX)`. `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD` (and `DelimitedSplitN4K_LEAD`) do *not* support `MAX` lengths, and the article above, and the original iteration of the function ([`DelimitedSplit8K`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function)) explain why.

Moving on, now we need to get onto the dynamic value. I'm going to *assume* that you won't have a "silly" value for `@Columns`, and that it'll be between 1 and 100. I'm also assuming you are using a recent version of SQL Server, and thus have access to `STRING_AGG`; if not you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to do the aggregation of the dynamic statement.

First we can use a tally with up to 100 rows, to get the right number of column groups, and then (like mentioned) `STRING_AGG` to aggregate the dynamic part. The rest of the statement is still static. With the variable we have before, we end up with something like this to create the dynamic statement:

```sql
DECLARE @Delimiter nvarchar(20) = N',' + @CRLF + N'       ';

WITH Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (@Columns)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N1(N)
         CROSS JOIN (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N2(N))
SELECT @SQL = N'WITH Groupings AS(' + @CRLF +
              N'    SELECT *,' + @CRLF +
              N'           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) -1) / @Columns AS RowNo,' + @CRLF +
              N'           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) -1) % @Columns +1 AS ColumnNo' + @CRLF +
              N'    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@String,'','') DS)' + @CRLF +
              N'SELECT ' + 
              (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(N'MAX(CASE G.ColumnNo WHEN ',T.I,N' THEN G.Item END) AS ',QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'Col',T.I))),@Delimiter) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.I)
               FROM Tally T) + @CRLF +              
              N'FROM Groupings G' + @CRLF +
              N'GROUP BY G.RowNo;'
PRINT @SQL;
```

And the `PRINT` outputs the below (which is what we had before, excellent!):

```sql
WITH Groupings AS(
    SELECT *,
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) -1) / @Columns AS RowNo,
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) -1) % @Columns +1 AS ColumnNo
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@String,',') DS)
SELECT MAX(CASE G.ColumnNo WHEN 1 THEN G.Item END) AS [Col1],
       MAX(CASE G.ColumnNo WHEN 2 THEN G.Item END) AS [Col2],
       MAX(CASE G.ColumnNo WHEN 3 THEN G.Item END) AS [Col3]
FROM Groupings G
GROUP BY G.RowNo;
```

Now we need to wrap this into a parametrised stored procedure, and also execute the dynamic statement. This gives us the following end result, using `sys.sp_executesql` to execute and parametrise the dynamic statement:

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.DynamicPivot @String varchar(8000), @Delim char(1), @Columns tinyint, @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = NULL OUTPUT AS
BEGIN
    IF @Columns > 100
        THROW 72001, N'@Columns cannot have a value greater than 100.', 16;

    DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

    DECLARE @Delimiter nvarchar(20) = N',' + @CRLF + N'       ';

    WITH Tally AS(
        SELECT TOP (@Columns)
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N1(N)
             CROSS JOIN (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N2(N))
    SELECT @SQL = N'WITH Groupings AS(' + @CRLF +
                  N'    SELECT *,' + @CRLF +
                  N'           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) -1) / @Columns AS RowNo,' + @CRLF +
                  N'           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) -1) % @Columns +1 AS ColumnNo' + @CRLF +
                  N'    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@String,@Delim) DS)' + @CRLF +
                  N'SELECT ' + 
                  (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(N'MAX(CASE G.ColumnNo WHEN ',T.I,N' THEN G.Item END) AS ',QUOTENAME(CONCAT(N'Col',T.I))),@Delimiter) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.I)
                   FROM Tally T) + @CRLF +              
                  N'FROM Groupings G' + @CRLF +
                  N'GROUP BY G.RowNo;'
    --PRINT @SQL;

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@String varchar(8000), @Delim char(1), @Columns tinyint', @String, @Delim, @Columns;
END;
GO
```

And then we can execute this like below:

```sql
EXEC dbo.DynamicPivot N'1,2,3,4,5,6',',',3; --Without @SQL
GO
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
EXEC dbo.DynamicPivot N'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10',' ',5,@SQL OUTPUT; --With SQL to see statement run, and different delimiter
PRINT @SQL;
```

As I noted as well, and as you can see from the definition of the Procedure, if you try to pivot with more than 100 columns it will error:

```sql
--Will error, too many columns
EXEC dbo.DynamicPivot N'1,2,3,4,5,6',',',101; --Without @SQL
```

Which returns the error:

> Msg 72001, Level 16, State 16, Procedure dbo.DynamicPivot, Line 5
> @Columns cannot have a value greater than 100.

*Edit: Noticed the value for the delimiter in the splitter needs to be parametrised too, so amended the SP's definition to add `@Delim` and added that the to dynamic SQL too and demonstrate in examples.*

Comment: This is a great write-up! I understand it's not ideal to do this in database engine, but it's the only way , because that's the way the menu items pass multirows (as query parameters) in the system, which I have no access to. When the user goes to the next step all the data i passed a single string.

 dbo.DynamicPivot worked perfectly, though the non-dynamic approach a lot easier, even if I'll have to go and change the code if a new column were to be added to list, I think that will have to do.

Comment: The dynamic version simply creates the SQL that you see in the first (non-dynamic) example @starbyone . Of course, it does "look" a little more complex, but there's (in truth) very little extra to it apart from having a Tally and a "tiny" bit of string aggregation.